# Set img src based on current URL in Nav with jQuery - similar to hover replace

Tags: jquery, url, navigation

I'm looking for something similar to this:
[Active navigation with jQuery - can't apply a default class to anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302955/active-navigation-with-jquery-cant-apply-a-default-class-to-anchor)

But I'm using images inside a unordered list and **I want to detect the current URL and append the img src with _over.jpg to show it being the current page.** *(no lectures on using BG position please - the client likes this.)*

I'm also using this easy hover (jQuery mouseover), which I bet will need to be adjusted...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".navbar li").each(function(){
        var link = $(this).children("a");
        var image = $(link).children("img");
        var imgsrc = $(image).attr("src");

        // add mouseover
        $(link).mouseover(function(){
            var on = imgsrc.replace(/.jpg$/gi,"_over.jpg");
            $(image).attr("src",on);
        });

        // add mouse out
        $(link).mouseout(function(){
            $(image).attr("src",imgsrc);
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic is in document.location.pathname :P

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navbar li").each(function(){
        var link = $(this).children("a");
        var image = $(link).children("img");
        var imgsrc = image.attr("src"); //no need to rewrap in $

        var on = imgsrc.replace(/.jpg$/gi,"_over.jpg");
            if (link.attr("href") == document.location.pathname || link.attr("href") == document.location.href)
            $(image).attr("src",on);
            else
                // add mouseover
                $(link).hover(function(){
                    $(image).attr("src",on);
                }, function(){
                    $(image).attr("src",imgsrc);
                });
    });
});
```

Why two conditions ORed in the if? Internet Explorer will return hostname (document.location.href) and Firefox/[WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) will return exactly what’s written on your link. But I would test for cross-browser issues if I was you.

Comment: That rocks and works too! Big Thanks.

Not too sure what you mean by "two conditions ORed in the if??"


Now, I'm wondering if we have variables behind a URL, like from a CMS pulling in article names, will the jquery still write _over.jpg to the nav img src?